# Increasing inventory in Torchlight 2

Tags: torchlight-2

I'm new to games like Torchlight 2 so I'm playing on casual difficulty to get used to it. Now I'm finding myself having to clear my inventory (loading my pet up with all unwanted equipment and sending him to town to sell it) 2 to 3 times every time I enter a dungeon. So at the moment it feels like I'm clearing my inventory excessively and wasting a lot of time this way.

Can I somehow increase my inventory size and/or is there some sort of a banker anywhere? Does increasing the difficulty level decrease the amount of drops you get?

Comment: How far along in the game are you? I played through most of the first act having the same issues but then started dying more often and selling in town when I did. Also try a harder difficulty, 10 minutes and you got the idea of what the game has to offer.

Comment: Just completed Act 1. So far having a wonderful time and still learning a lot of things and getting more and more questions the longer I progress. I'm definitely going to increase my difficulty level in the future :)

Comment: Torchlight is designed to discourage hoarding.  I am trying to get used to this myself as I tend to hoard.  Sell the items you aren't using, and check the vendors every time you go into town - they sometimes have better loot than stuff I find.  Using the vendors is almost required on Elite Hardcore in order to find better gear.  Difficulty doesn't affect loot drops.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no way to increase your basic inventory size (note: mods could change that in the future).  However, there are **two** stashes in town: the personal stash and the shared stash.  The shared stash is accessible by every character on your account.  In  the starting town the two stashes are near the top-most exit; each stash looks like a chest but their appearances are unique.

Note that you can filter what drops you can actually see in the options screen.  Are you picking up lots of whites?  My advice there would be not to bother, and to filter them out.

Difficulty does not affect drop levels.

Comment: Everything i needed to know. I have a bit of a hoarder in my genes so everything i see gets picked up, i'm gonna head straight over to the filter so i hopefully 'forget' about picking those whites up :) Thanks

Comment: Finally, your pet has an inventory and can be sent to town to sell stuff. So all that not enchanted or basic enchantment etc, just give to pet and send off to sale.

Comment: OP has already stated that he uses his pet. I would continue selling whites, as they bring in a decent income. In Torchlight 1, there was a skill that allowed the pet to come back quicker, and I assume town portals still exist.

Comment: If you send pet to town, then portal there you will meet pet in town and get pet and money instantly, there is also more than one town in torchlight 2 so maximum pet travel time is 2 minutes.

Comment: Also note, that with the shared stash you can effectively move any item to any character, which means that if you want to you can have infinite stashes by creating new characters for each stash. For example, making a character named sword for only your swords you want stashed, you would move your swords from your main characters inventory into the shared stash, which then would be picked up by sword, to be put into his normal stash.

Answer (score 3):

Sending your pet to town is commonplace in Torchlight - with their ability to buy things for you it's not such a hassle to send them back anymore either.

Also, don't just wait for your pet to return - I'm constantly sending him out and back while progressing as needed.

The difficulty does not have an affect on the drops as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the above answer by peacedog, there is no way to increase the inventory size. The sending pet to town feature itself is added for saving time on clearing the inventory.

Having completed the game, I would say that clearing the inventory is not a daunting task. In fact it earns for enchantments and other services from the merchants. When you get a better item than the one you use currently, use it and sell all others. It almost never helps to stack items in stashes/inventory, because, by the time you use it, a better one will be dropped. Same case with socketables too. As the game tip suggests, use our socketables then and there.

Shared stash is a cool way of storing any good character specific items for other characters that you may find along the ways.

Answer (score -2):

I completed Torchlight II in casual difficulty - killed that Boss in Clockwork & got an option to play game in + where it again started with monster level same & above my current level.

There is a magic wherein you can learn it to decrease the time of your pets return.

**What I did - class Embermage**

I use to explore the entire region - killing everything and picking every item dropped (I usually get enough to fill 2 bag space - mine & pet's). Then when I start heading to 1 quest (usually stair to some cave) I send pet to town, 'til it returns I reach the cave so it assist me in clearing & when I get out, I send it again to town with items to sell & I head to next location....

The magic I enabled for my pet: **silence**, **summons** (skeleton & nymph) & **Heal ally**

The magic I enabled for myself:  **pet handling**, some magic where it give additional gold for selling item, more gold drop. All these magic are always available so I don't need to click them again & again.

Comment: This...doesn't really answer how to increase your inventory.